# How can I make fried potatoes crunchy in a multicooker?

Tags: frying, potatoes

- [Maestro Multi Cooker MR-795](https://feel-maestro.eu/catalog/electrical-products/steamers-multi-cookers/multi-cooker-mr795/)

I am using this multicooker to fry potatoes to eat with rice.

Recipe:

1. Cut a big potato into cubes
2. Wash that potato in cold water and remove excess water using kitchen towel
3. Add teaspoons of turmeric and salt
4. Select the **`[Fry, 170°]`**-option and add a table spoon of olive oil
5. Add the potato and cook for 10 minutes with lid on
6. Open the lid and stir the potato so that it doesn't burn on one side
7. Remove the potato when it looks golden brown

The problem is that the potato is not becoming crunchy.

What am I doing incorrectly?

How can I make fried potatoes crunchy in a multicooker?